# Building scalable SPAs using websockets, how complex is it?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, websocket, single-page-application

I am beginner in web technologies. While studying about frontend frameworks, I came to know that we run separate application servers for frontend and backend server(API).
e.g. If I am using vue.js, I'll be running a vue server for frontend and I'll be running another MEAN stack API server separately. Now my application will need to show real-time updates, I'll have to use websocket connection between my browser and frontend server which further will need websocket/webhook connection with my backend server(API). Now I am already aware of the scalability and session management issues with websocket connection. In this scenario, how should I build my application for better scalability and with less complexity? Is it possible to create a monolithic application server for frontend and backend? Will that be a good choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a monolithic application server for frontend and backend? Will that be a good choice?

That choice is fine; start simple and you can break into microservices in the future. Unless this is for a large production system!

If you use something like express you can serve the Vue.js files using `express.static`, API endpoints using `express.Router()` instances, and the `ws` or `socket.io` module attached to express instance for websockets.

> Now my application will need to show real-time updates, I'll have to
>   use websocket connection between my browser and frontend server which
>   further will need websocket/webhook connection with my backend server

This isn't the case. You can have your frontend (the app running in a browser) connect directly to the backend via websocket if you wish, no need to proxy via a frontend server. For session management look into JWT tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for socket.io library in Nodejs. It's simple and easy to use, The scalability and session can be handled by introducing Redis,

check https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/